# Перевод метки [geolocation]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, переименование-метки

У нас есть метка [geolocation](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/geolocation). В русском языке есть слово [геолокация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b3%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f), которым, я считаю, нужно заменить иностранную метку, сделав английское слово синонимом.